# Swing,JTextAreas are blank

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

Class principal :

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Random;
    public class Principal extends Guii {
    public int combo;
    public static Random bulion = new Random();
    public static boolean sansa;
    public static boolean input;
    public int status;

    //STATUS 0 = HEADS;
    //STATUS 1 = TAILS;

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Guii lee = new Guii();
            Principal obiect = new Principal();

        }

        public int flip(){
        boolean sansa2 ;
        sansa2 = bulion.nextBoolean();
        if(sansa2){
           status = 0;
            display.setText("Heads");
        }
        else{
            status = 1;
            display.setText("Tails");
        }
        return status;

    }

     public int returnStatus(){
         return status;
     }
}
```

Class Guii :

```
    import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.Dimension;



public class Guii extends JFrame{
    Principal obiect;
    public JButton heads = new JButton("Heads");
    public JButton tails = new JButton("Tails");
    public JTextArea display = new JTextArea();
    public JTextArea comboul = new JTextArea();
        private JPanel panel;
        public int predictie;

        public Guii(){
            super("Heads or Tails");
            setContentPane(panel);

            pack();
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            setVisible(true);}
    public void dacaHeads(){
        if(heads.getModel().isPressed()) predictie = 0;
    }
    public void dacaTails(){
        if(tails.getModel().isPressed()) predictie = 1;

        heads.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                dacaHeads();
                obiect.flip();

                if(predictie == obiect.returnStatus() ){
                    String s = comboul.getText();
                    int combo = Integer.valueOf(s);
                    s = Integer.toString(++combo);
                    comboul.setText("asdsaad");}
                else{
                    String z = "0";
                    comboul.setText("asdasda");
                }
            }
        });

        tails.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                dacaTails();
                obiect.flip();
                if(predictie == obiect.returnStatus() ){
                    String s = comboul.getText();
                    int combo = Integer.valueOf(s);
                    s = Integer.toString(++combo);
                    comboul.setText(s);}
                else{
                    String z = "0";
                    comboul.setText(z);
                }
            }
    });}
```

The problem is that the window opens, i see everything but nothing happens when i press the buttons.
I used gui designer from intellij idea.
Thank you.
//Sorry for the second question.Deleted it.

Comment: *"Also 2 windows open instead of one."*  Ask one question, rather than describe two problems.  SO is a Q&A site, not a help desk.  Separate questions should be put in separate threads.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it is a mistake of writing your code but your function dacaTails(), which add the listener to the button, seems to be never called. You should put the addActionListener's functions in the constructor method, I think.

Comment: Can you so updated your post with the new code, please ?

Comment: I could get something with adding @Override to the actionPerformed, try it to see. There is still some NumberFormatException and NUllPointer but I assume the code you post is minimal for the forum